# In MEAN web app, sending HTTP response error 403, 500 from Express (server side), not captured in errorCallback function in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

In my Node web app, I'm sending an HTTP GET request in one of the Angular controllers, and in the same route defined in Express, somewhere in the route logic, I'm sending an HTTP 500 response (tried 403 Error as well). In the Angular controller, this error is not captured in the correct callback function, any insights?

**myApp/public/javascripts/main_controller.js**:

```
mainApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $routeParams) 
{
    ...
    $scope.myFunction = function (profile) {

     $http({
        url: '/route1/" + username, 
        method: "POST"
      })
      .then(function successCallback(response) 
      {
        //ERROR: This is printed after the GET request  
        console.log("success updating likes");

      },  function errorCallback(response) 
      {
        //ERROR: This is NOT printed after the GET request 
        console.log("error: ", response.error);
     });

  };

});
```

**myApp/routes/api.js**:

```
router.route('/route1/:username')
  .post(function(req, res) {
   User.findOne({'user': param1 }, function (err, user)
  {
     //...Logic to Find and update a property of collection
     if (user.property == condition)
     {
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'some error' });
     } 
    //...Other logic
  })
  });
```

Comment: Though it should work anyway, but try to `return` from `res.status` or else your code will continue to run and it could be getting confused somewhere and sending multiple headers if you have more `res` below.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: I'll just move that down to answer so you can check off and this can be closed. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it should work anyway, but try to return from res.status or else your code will continue to run and it could be getting confused somewhere and sending multiple headers if you have more res below.